# Tag synonym/merge: virtual{host,hosts,-hosting,-hosts}

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

These tags all seem to refer to the same things, and people are using all of them interchangeably.  Personally, I'd have picked the one that nobody seems to have gone for [virtual-host](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtual-host) but I guess I'm out of touch with today's urban sysadmin.  I don't have any other preference, but whichever one the mods choose, I'll commit to writing a tag wiki for it.

As an aside, if you stare at the tag search page for 'virtual', the word starts lose all meaning eventually...

Comment: Man you're busy this early in the morning ;) I'll take look at all the tags

Comment: Insomnia's a terrible thing, and I can't go outside because it's persisting down raining.

Comment: Tell me about it. I start work at 7.30 and it took me 10 mins longer to get here just because of the rain.

Comment: P.S. I believe the correct tag is `virtualhost` because that's the actual name of the Apache directive.

Comment: @Mark: If you took the train to work, it wasn't my fault; I'm off today.  <grin>

Comment: @Womble - nope, I drive. Good old lack of public transport to the north west. Anyway unless you do the Carlingford line... Hey are you one of those smart-arses who does announcements like "Today we will be cruising at 3.5 feet" and "Attention all passengers: You will find the ride more comfortable if you don't all try to squeeze through the first doors on the train all at once"

Comment: I don't drive the carlingford line much any more.  It's the guard that does the announcements, so I don't have anything to do with that at all.  Being a guard is a very boring job, I'm not surprised they make weird announcements now and then to relieve the boredom.

Comment: Well, if you did the carlingford line 18 months ago you might have given me a trip to work. Well to Clyde at least. Must be cushy line to do. Drive 5 stations, have a smoke, have another smoke, walk to the other end of the train, rinse, repeat.

Comment: That walking 60 metres every half hour *sucks*.  It's a tough job driving trains.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Merged:

[virtualhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost) <- [virtual-host](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtual-host)
[virtualhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost) <- [virtual-hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts)
[virtualhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost) <- [virtualhosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualhosts)

I have not done [virtual-hosting](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosting) because those questions actually seem to relate to VPS's and not apache directives.

Also, I see what you mean about the word Virtual losing all meaning ;)

Comment: When I did a quick scan of [virtual-hosting] I only noticed the one (closed) question regarding virtualisation.  Now you point it out I noticed a few more open ones, so I've retagged those [virtualization] because it is...

Comment: I think we must be looking at different questions then. I see 5, of which I've re-tagged 1, leaving: http://serverfault.com/questions/242682/new-to-server-hosting-what-do-i-need-to-know-should-i and http://serverfault.com/questions/198960/setting-up-procmail-filtering-for-spam-on-postfix-couriermysql-virtual-users and http://serverfault.com/questions/156619/magento-community-hosting-need-advice-which-sharing-hosting-will-run-magento and http://serverfault.com/questions/63518/how-can-i-forward-mail-while-saving-a-copy-using-postfix-and-mysql

Comment: I think we both must have retagged the same questions, those are the four I see left in [virtual-hosting].