# Virtual Hosting tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag synonym/merge: virtual{host,hosts,-hosting,-hosts}](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1788/tag-synonym-merge-virtualhost-hosts-hosting-hosts)

I am not sure if i should post this kind of things here.

Should I?

I recommend that the tags: [virtualhosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualhosts), [virtual-host](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtual-host) and [virtual-hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts) should be merged.

Regards.

Comment: This is exactly the place to suggest it :) Looks like someone else already beat me to it though.

Comment: This is duplicated. Thank you so much for your help. I don't know how to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already [handled some time ago](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1788/tag-synonym-merge-virtualhost-hosts-hosting-hosts); can you give an example of where things still aren't right (a link to a question or two would do).

Comment: Thanks to you and @Mark, this was done some time ago. It was my fault.  ¿Should I delete the question, right?

Comment: Close as dupe is better.

Comment: how can i closte it?

Comment: Apparently, wait for a mod to come along.  <grin>